# C#- XML Documentation not available from another project

Tags: c#, xml, comments

I'm working on an ASP.NET website. To the solution I've added another project that serves as a Data Access Layer(DAL). Whenever I build the project the dll file gets refreshed to the new one in the website project.I've put XML comments before each method in all the classes of the DAL. But they're not available when I type the method names of this layer. However they're visible from their own project. Is XML documentation only internal? if so, how can I see other classes' XML comments?

Comment: You really mean the "Web Site" variation of ASP.NET? Ie not Web Application?

Comment: Does your DAL project has "XML documentation file" option enabled on the Build tab of the project properties?

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin - in a normal solution that is not required for IntelliSense.

Comment: @ Sergey Rybalkin my answer is yes to both of your questions.

Comment: @ Henk Holterman- I chose ASP.NET website when choosing from the project templates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to check the XML documentation file for the output build setting. (properties on your project).  Then you will generate the xml documentation that the other project will use when you add a reference to it.

There are 2 ways that you probably are adding the reference.

1.) By choosing "Add reference" then "Project"

- This method should just work... as you update the comments the other
  project should pickup the changes automatically.

2.) By choosing "Add reference" then "BROWSE"...

- If you did it this way then every time the XML file changes you need to unload and reload the project for it to pickup the changes or you can restart visual studio which will accomplish the same thing.

**You should use version 1... Add reference-->Project**

Comment: I've added the reference to my DAL project by browsing so that refresh file also gets generated. After a while I can now see the XML documentation for my objects. But when I check to generate XML file in Build I get warnings for all the items in my project that are not XML Documented. Is there a way to avoid these warnings?

Comment: you could use "#pragma warning disable" in each of the file you want to suppress warning in... see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This worked for me. I had XML documentation from another project in the same solution would not appear during editing. I'd previously added the Reference using method 2 ("Add Reference"->BROWSE). Changing to using method 1 ("Add Reference"->"Project") worked. Interestingly all other things did work, just not the documentation.

Using the second method for project in different solutions works fine (it's possibly the only option?).

Answer (score 1):

If your project file and referenced project file on

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Try add GenerateDocumentationFile to referenced project

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```